# Ошибка отображения дня в году

Tags: php, парсер, время

Есть скрипт, его задача выполняться несколько раз в день и проверять наличие обновления данных на другом сайте, для этого храню время, когда последний раз было обновление данных на том сайте и при повторном запуске с помощью *Cron* я проверяю, это тоже время или уже позже(было обновлено, если было, то обновляю у себя данные). Но ближе к вечеру возникает такая проблема, что появляются данные, которые были утром. Получается, если данные обновляются допустим в 8, 12, 16, то при вечернем запуске он покажет данные снова с 8 утра. Делаю я это таким кодом:

```php
$timesp = date("z");
$day = file_get_contents('day.txt');

if($day != $timesp){
   file_put_contents('time.txt', '0');
   file_put_contents('day.txt', $timesp);
}
```

Было предположение, что это из-за того, что на сервере происходит переход уже на новый день, а на сайте еще старое расписание. Но нет, время у всех московское. Начал копать глубже и нашел [сайт](http://calendarin.net/ru/day-number-in-year), на котором показывает, что сейчас *254* день в году, а мой скрипт показывает, что сегодня *253*. В чем может быть проблема? Из-за чего он вечером начинает отсчет заново? Если он начинает отсчет заново, значит происходит какое-то изменение в параметрах, приводящее к обнулению счетчика. Но я не могу понять, почему?

Comment: может я что то не так понял )) а почему вы не храните время в миллисекундах,  time() , это же без погрешностей..

Comment: @Arsen, время обновления на сайте указано, если вы про это.

Comment: а в каком формате на сайте ? думаю у вас проблемы в временной зоне, поэтому и расходятся даты. Вы проверяли во время обновления? дата с сайта и ваша - одинаковы  ? я заметил что вы написали " время у всех московское"  но может стоит перепроверить ?

Comment: ещё одна мысль пришла  > Из-за чего он вечером начинает отсчет заново?  вы проверили, у вас обоих время в 24 часовом формате?

Comment: @Arsen Да, потому что вечернее обновление получается, это где-то часов в 6, а позже уже сбоит иногда, причем раз через раз, раз нормально, а раз обнуляется.

Comment: ну по всей вероятности у вас CRON  глючит (зависает), такое часто бывает, детально проверьте работу крон, установите несколько задач в разное время в течении дня и, высылайте себе письма, тем самым отловите момент когда запустился крон и т.д

Comment: @Arsen, проверял, его работа в норме. Происходит именно обнуление счетчика, по непонятным мне пока причинам.